# "Set a property for JavaHome in your CSPROJ file"

Tags: c#, msbuild, antlr

I am trying to build [this project](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrHW).

I have installed Java.

When I try to build, I get the following error:

> `AC1000`  Unknown build error: Cannot find Java home, currently set to '"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221"' Please set either the JAVA_HOME environment variable, or set a property for JavaHome in your CSPROJ file.

I know how to set environment variables, but how would I go about setting the property in the `.csproj` file?

(NB. In an email communication, the project author confirmed that the property name should also be `JAVA_HOME`, not `JavaHome`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click on your project (not solution!) in solution explorer.
It will open `YourProjectName.csproj`. Here you can find (or add it yourself) a property group tag.

```
<PropertyGroup>
</PropertyGroup>
```

There should be no attributes like `Condition`.
Just add your property in it like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <JavaHome>C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\Java</JavaHome>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: `\\ ` instead of `\ `?

Comment: You can try both. Windows understands (and works better sometimes!) when there are two backslashes.

Comment: Ubuntu Linux acts the same. So you can use whatever you like more.